# Instalar proyecto/aplicacion web hecha en laravel en local

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Pues tengo hecho ya un pequeño sistema en laravel y quiero implementarlo en una pc que no es la mía.

Esa pc usará ese sistema y todos los demás dispositivos en la red también deberían usarlo, en teoría. Pero no se como hacerlo :/ los tutoriales me dicen como suvirlo a hosting en la nube y no es eso lo que busco. Es que corra de manera local en un pc apenas lo encienda.

Tenía entendido que para eso era el. Xampp, que funcionaba como Host local. Pero cuando programaba usaba php artisan serve (con una base ya en la nube), y pues no necesitaba del xampp. Entonces no se que hacer, como implemento ese sistema de manera local en otras pcs?

Edit1: Sistema operativo windows

Comment: @BetaM lo siento, son windows

Comment: No es tan complicado permitir que otros equipos en tu red [tengan acceso al servidor con XAMPP](https://nosololinux.es/permitir-acceso-a-xampp-desde-cualquier-pc/)

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar Laravel no te vas a librar de XAMPP (en Windows), ya que Laravel corre en PHP que a su vez corre en Apache (o NGIN-X)

La ventaja de XAMPP es que ya incluye todo lo necesario para que puedas crear tu servidor web de pruebas, asi que no es obligatorio que uses artisan serve para correr tu aplicacion, simplemente lo configuras para que encienda de forma automatica cada vez que prendan la computadora y ademas se enciendan los servicios que necesites (usualmente solo Apache y MySQL)

Artisan Serve es un mini servidor para los casos cuando tienes PHP instalado pero no tienes (o no puedes o no quieres) tener Apache o NGINX

Una vez encendido XAMPP solo visitas localhost en tu navegador local y entras a la carpeta public para ver tu aplicacion, o si estas desde una computadora externa tienes que colocar la IP de la computadora que esta corriendo XAMPP, recuerda siempre dejar una IP local fija o de lo contrario tendras que cambiarla a cada rato en las computadoras cliente, o si tienes un servidor DNS puedes configurarlo para usar dominios en vez de direcciones IP, pero eso ya es mas avanzado

Comment: gracias por aclarar la duda del Artusan Serve, si, en efecto soy un novato. Me a tocado el diseño, mas no el de utilizar el framework a profundidad. Logre accerder desde el celular y otras pc en la red, hice el vhost pero...p ara acceder tengo que que ingresar la ip del pc y no el ServerName   en los otros dispositivos, pero planteare mi duda enotra regunta. Gracias a todos